# SSL certificate transfer | IIS server

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I had a Windows 2012 server and I no longer have access to that server. I have a new Windows 2012 server which I am using IIS to host my websites. Previously I purchased an SSL certificate for the site and completed the usual process in IIS to create a CSR then get it added on.

Now that I have a new server I have manually added the site back and now I am interested in setting the SSL for the site again. I have the old CSR and certificate files, how would I add the SSL for the site again?

Comment: The private key will/should have stayed on the original server, unless you backed it up.  If that's the case, the certificate and the CSR are useless to you.  You'll need a new certificate.

Comment: does this mean i have to buy a new certificate?

Comment: If you didn't take a backup and you can't get access to the original server, then you'll need to purchase a replacement.